# Is there a way to stop testNG execution when exception occurs validating in Listeners

Tags: testng

I am using Selenium TestNG framework. I have used Listeners (ITestListener, ISuiteListener, IInvokedMethodListener, IHookable) to get the status of test suite. I have handled exceptions in the script, but whenever there is an exception I wanted testNG to stop the execution.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like that?

```
public class MyHook implements IHookable {

  private static boolean failed = false;

  public void run(final IHookCallBack icb, ITestResult testResult) {
    if (failed) {
      return;
    }

    try {
      icb.callback(testResult);
    } catch(Exception ex) {
      failed = true;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for the response. I have selenium script used through testNG where in when there is unexpected thing happened such as "NoSuchElementException"/"NoAIertPresentException" I  wanted to forcefully stop testNG through code.